# Pilha - Ruby Wrapper to the Stack Exchange API

Tags: library, ruby

**Warning**: there's still a lot of work to be done.

**Edit**: Pilha has been updated and now it supports most of the stack exchange api. There's still work to be done and the gem should be completely functional by the end of this week. Watch the github repo to keep track of the latest updates.

### Code Snippet

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'pilha'

include StackExchange::StackOverflow

StackExchange::StackOverflow.config do |options|
  options.api_key = 'your key goes here'
end

response = Answer.all
answer = response.answers.first
answer.answers_comments_url    # "/answers/123/comments"
answer.owner                   # <StackExchange::StackOverflow::User:0x93234b8  ...> 
answer.owner.display_name      " "john smith"
```

### About

Pilha aims to provide an ActiveRecord-like interface for querying the StackExchange API.

More info about the gem can be founded at its github page: http://github.com/dlt/pilha

Desing goals:

- Simplicity
- No external dependencies/gems
- Lots of specs/tests

#### License

The MIT License

#### Download

To install it, just gem install pilha.
The library's code is hosted in github (http://github.com/dlt/pilha).

#### Platform

Tested under Ruby 1.8.7 (Enterprise Edition)

### Contact

[my username] @ gmail.com

### Code

This library is written in Ruby and uses Rspec for its tests. Anyone can contribute to the code by sending a pull request.

Comment: That's an odd choice of name.  Any particular reason for that?

Comment: Pilha means 'stack' in portuguese. :)

Comment: The last commit on this project was in 2011. Does it still work/is it being maintained?